# If this page is products echo

Tags: php

I have this element on everypage :

```
$thisPage="products";
```

I need to show this code when the page is products

```
<link href="<?php if ($thisPage=="products") echo "../../../"; ?>css/agency.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

I tried that code but without success

```
<?php if ($thisPage="products"){ echo "../../../";} else { echo ""; }   ?>
```

Comment: You know `!=` means not equal, right?

Comment: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Comment: sorry i post with wrong code, i tried with == but does not work

Comment: How are you determining that your code isn't working? What is it you expect to see vs what you're actually seeing? I also suggest you make sure errors are reported correctly. Add this to the top of your PHP ~ `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 'On');`

Answer (score -1):

Sorry guys, the error was i didnt put the subfolder on patch, the php was working fine.

thanks